Prototype pollution between functions and plain objects
There seems to be some asymmetry in prototype pollution between functions and "plain"1 objects:


var a = {}
function foo(){}

a.__proto__.something = 32;
foo.__proto__.bar = 67;

console.log(a.bar) // <--- not polluted
console.log(foo.something) // <--- polluted




The example shows that plain objects can pollute functions
Is the other way around possible too? (functions polluting plain objects)


1 terminology is not a consensus (see here)

functions are objects

@Pointy agreed, but the example shows there is some difference in the aspect of "polluting" effect

all functions are objects. Not all objects are functions.

Yes, but the question remains - can a function pollute a plain object ? or can I count on it that from a security perspective this is impossible ?

A function object has in its prototype chain the Function prototype and the Object prototype. A plain object has in its prototype chain the Object prototype. It's not clear what is confusing about that.

So you're saying the answer is: no, it is not possible (just making sure)

If you change the Function prototype, you affect all Function instances, but not all Object instances. If you change the Object prototype, you affect all Object instances and any instances of things that inherit from Object.

third comment answers your question :p

@JaromandaX I would say I mostly fear I miss some weird things like (in pseudo-code: ) var b = (Object) foo which would consolidate prototypes or something similar ...

that pseudo code doesn't make sense even as pseudo code :p

It makes pseudo sense :) I meant casting - I know it's irrelevant but javascript is the queen of weird behaviors ...


There seems to be some asymmetry between functions and "plain" objects

Sure. A plain object inherits from Object.prototype, but a function inherits from Function.prototype, which in turn inherits from Object.prototype. Object.prototype inherits from nothing (null), not from Function.prototype.

Is it possible to do prototype pollution of plain objects from functions?

Yes, you just have to chain a bit longer:


var a = {}
function foo(){}

foo.__proto__.__proto__.bar = 42;
foo.prototype.__proto__.qux = 67;

console.log(a.bar) // <--- polluted
console.log(a.qux) // <--- polluted



